# Monitor and video mode querying

Tags: c++, c++11, windows

I am working on a large project that requires information about the monitor(s). Please don't be confused by the organization of the following structs. The design intent is to be cross-platform, so they don't contain any operating system-dependent types. Currently, I am working on the Windows implementation of the following functions.

Please bear with me as I am a beginner at C++. Even though I have been programming with it for a while now, I am completely self taught, and my understanding isn't comprehensive.

Is there anything I could be doing differently, or maybe better? Also, is there anything I am not understanding correctly? I'm open to any and all suggestions, tips, and criticisms.

```
/**
 * Monitor structure.
 */
struct tsMonitor
{
    /**
     * Windows specific data.
     */
    typedef struct SWin32 { std::string adapterName; std::string displayName; } _win32;

    std::string adapterName;            // Name of the adapter (GPU).
    std::string displayName;            // Actual monitor name.

    _win32 win32;                       // Windows adapter and display names. Fuck you Windows and your stupid "DeviceName" vs "DeviceString".

    unsigned short widthMM, heightMM;   // Physical dimensions in millimeters.
};

/**
 * Video mode structure.
 */
struct tsVideoMode
{
    unsigned short width, height;   // Dimensions in pixels.

    unsigned char refreshRate;      // Refresh rate.

    unsigned char colorDepth;       // Number of bits per pixel.
};

std::vector<tsMonitor> tsGetMonitors()
{
    std::vector<tsMonitor> returnVal;

    for(unsigned char adapterIndex = 0;; adapterIndex++)
    {
        DISPLAY_DEVICE adapter;

        ZeroMemory(&adapter, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
        adapter.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

        if(!EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, adapterIndex, &adapter, 0)) break;
        if(!(adapter.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)) continue;

        for(unsigned char displayIndex = 0;; displayIndex++)
        {
            DISPLAY_DEVICE display;

            ZeroMemory(&display, sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE));
            display.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

            if(!EnumDisplayDevices(adapter.DeviceName, displayIndex, &display, 0)) break;

            HDC hDC = CreateDC("DISPLAY", adapter.DeviceName, NULL, nullptr);

            tsMonitor monitor;

            monitor.adapterName = adapter.DeviceString;
            monitor.displayName = display.DeviceString;

            monitor.win32.adapterName = adapter.DeviceName;
            monitor.win32.displayName = display.DeviceName;

            monitor.widthMM = (unsigned short)GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZSIZE);
            monitor.heightMM = (unsigned short)GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTSIZE);

            returnVal.push_back(monitor);
        }
    }

    return returnVal;
}

unsigned char tsGetMonitorCount()
{
    return (unsigned char)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS); // NOTE: I don't exactly understand pseudo-monitors.
}

bool tsGetVideoMode(const tsMonitor& monitor, tsVideoMode* mode)
{
    DEVMODE devMode;

    ZeroMemory(&devMode, sizeof(DEVMODE));
    devMode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

    if(!EnumDisplaySettings(monitor.win32.adapterName.c_str(), ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devMode)) return false;

    mode->width = (unsigned short)devMode.dmPelsWidth;
    mode->height = (unsigned short)devMode.dmPelsHeight;
    mode->refreshRate = (unsigned char)devMode.dmDisplayFrequency;
    mode->colorDepth = (unsigned char)devMode.dmBitsPerPel;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm forced to vote to close--as it stands now, the code doesn't even seem to compile.

Comment: Could you point out the error? It compiled mms for me

Comment: The first couple of things I ran into were use (but no definition) of `tsMonitor` and `tsVideoMode`.

Comment: Oh I forgot to include the typedefs. I'll just edit it

Comment: Chances are it won't get answered anyway, since it's far down the list now

Answer (score 4):

I have some general comments as I'm not too familiar with the Windows API.

- Comments that are just tautologies are not very useful
- `typedef struct` is a pointless idiom in C++, as C++ doesn't have tag names
- Why are you using `unsigned short` (2 bytes wide) when the DEVMODE structure uses DWORD (32-bits wide)? In general, you should use the Windows typedef to stay consistent and avoid unnecessary type issues
- You have some redundant casts, like in `tsGetMonitorCount()`. Also C-style casts can sometimes silence warnings which is not what you want
- Why does `tsGetVideoMode` return a `bool`? I would expect it to return a video mode
- The "Fuck you Windows" comment is unprofessional and unlikely to impress any readers of your code. I (and future readers) will also have no idea what the purpose of the comment is, so it's useless altogether

Comment: Thank you for your input. As for the comment, this code is proprietary. The only reason it's here is because I was looking for input. It's a person comment. Also, like I said above, I'm using primitive types because this is cross platform and the functions are just Windows implementations. Again, thank you for your input!